# How do I change the element next to my cursor while dragging and dropping?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I am trying to incorporate drag and drop functionality into my application that uses Google Closure libraries. Specifically, I am using the `goog.fx.DragDropGroup` class:

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_fx_DragDropGroup.html

Now, I am trying to have the element next to my cursor be some element other than the drag source. I have tried doing this in callback function of my event listener for a `dragstart` event.

```
myapp.Foo.prototype.dragStart_ = 
    function(e) {
  var dElement = goog.dom.createElement('div');
  dElement.innerHTML = 'This element is not a copy of the drag source element.';
  e.dropTargetItem.element = dElement;
}
```

However, directly changing the `element` property of the drop target item does not work. In fact, it does away with any copy of the drag source element while dragging and dropping.

How can I specify another element to be the element that appears while dragging the drag source around with my mouse? I don't want this element to be identical to the drag source.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a draggroup class that inherits from goog.fx.DragGroup
Then override the function: createDragElement
The element you return will be the element that follows the mouse pointer.

Example:

```
goog.provide('my.DragGroup');

goog.require('goog.fx.DragDropGroup')

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.fx.DragDropGroup}
 */
my.DragGroup = function() {
    goog.base(this);
};
goog.inherits(my.DragGroup, goog.fx.DragDropGroup); 

/** @inheritDoc */
my.DragGroup.prototype.createDragElement = function(sourceEl) {
    return goog.dom.createDom('div', null, 'Not a copy of the source El');
}
```

Hope this helps